# How to use Matlab Command window in a cluster

Tags: matlab, stream, matlab-figure

I wrote below code to show streamlines and velocity vector field in 2D. But it doesn't show streamlines in up-left and bottom-right of the output. How can I show streamlines in total space?

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:1,-1:0.1:1);
u = x;
v = -y;figure
quiver(x,y,u,v)
startx = -1:0.1:1;
starty = ones(size(startx));
starty = -1:0.1:1;
streamline(x,y,u,v,startx,starty)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

```
streamline(x,y,u,v,[startx -startx],[starty starty])
```

[image: streams]